# Detect which UICollectionViewCell of a uicollectionView that is inside another uicollectionview is in the center

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

So i have a horizontal UICollectionView of images that is inside a vertical UICollectionView and i want to detect which cell is in the center on the horizonal UICollectionView when i select a cell from the vertical one
I tried to send a notification and call a function that does the work but its called multiple times since its reusing the same cell so at the end i dont get the appropriate indexPath.

And also when i tap on an image the "didSelectItemAt" of the horizontal collectionView is called, is there a way to get the vertical one to be called instead ?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be delegates via protocols

Create protocol for your collection view cells

```
protocol yourDelegate: class {
    
    func didSelectCell(WithIndecPath indexPath: IndexPath, InCollectionView collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Void
    
}
```

In your cells, create a function called setup which you can call at cellForRow.
In your cells, create a touch recogniser for self.
Disable cell selection for your collection views since these delegates will be called when the user touches given cell.

```
class yourCell: UICollectionViewCell  {
    
    var indexPath: IndexPath? = nil
    var collectionView: UICollectionView? = nil
    
    weak var delegate: yourDelegate? = nil
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        let selfTGR = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTouchSelf))
        self.contentView.addGestureRecognizer(selfTGR)
    }
    
    @objc func didTouchSelf() {
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView, let indexPath = self.indexPath else {
            return
        }
        
        delegate?.didSelectCell(WithIndecPath: indexPath, InCollectionView: collectionView)
    }
    
    func setupCell(WithIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath, CollectionView collectionView: UICollectionView, Delegate delegate: yourDelegate) {
        self.indexPath = indexPath
        self.collectionView = collectionView
        self.delegate = delegate
    }
    
}
```

In your viewController, create extension for this protocol and if you do everything right, when the user touches your cell, the cell will call you via this delegation.

```
extension YourViewController: yourDelegate {
    
    func didSelectCell(WithIndecPath indexPath: IndexPath, InCollectionView collectionView: UICollectionView) {
        //You have your index path and you can "if" your colllection view
        
        if collectionView == self.yourFirstCollectionView {
            
        } else if collectionView == self.yourSecondCollectionView {
            
        }
        //and so on..
    }
    
}
```

since protocol is ": class", we can use weak for your delegate property so no memory leak will occur. I use this method for tableViews and collectionViews throughout my projects.

Comment: @VinceMohamed I am glad :) Please accept the answer if it helped you